# how to have Custom DB field as some value instead null while creating custom field in acumatica

Tags: database, acumatica

I have a custom field to be created which is DB field. Initial value of the "Forecast to Complete" field is null even though default value is 0.0.

How do i get the DB field 0.00 initially?

[PXDBDecimal(2)]

[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]

[PXUIField(DisplayName="Forecast To Complete")]

Comment: CustomizationPlugin to run during publish or you can use a raw-default value on your field on the table in the project.xml file. Is this a Usr field or a custom table?

Comment: It is a Usrfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's a mechanism assigning a null value after the field has been initialized.

If the record is created from UI you can try setting `AllowNull` property to `False` value:

```
<px:PXNumberEdit ID="edForecastToComplete" runat="server" AllowNull="False" 
                 DataField="ForecastToComplete" Decimals="4" ValueType="Decimal" />
```

Worst case scenario you can force the assignation to be non null using C# property setter and backing field:

```
public decimal? _forecastToComplete;

[PXDBDecimal]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Forecast to Complete")]
public virtual decimal? ForecastToComplete 
{ 
   get { return _forecastToComplete != null ? _forecastToComplete : 0M; }   
   set { _forecastToComplete = value != null ? value : 0M }
}

public abstract class forecastToComplete : IBqlField { }
```

Comment: Get and set is only for UI. not for the DB know. My requirement is to add a custom DB field for the Table which is already exist.

Comment: There's multiple level. If the record was created (inserted) by a screen you can add AllowNull=False to the editor control. If it's created by web service the property setter will do. If it's created by a DB script and you need it initialize as soon as possible you could set AllowNull=False directly on the SQL field too.

Answer (score 1):

`PXDefaultAttribute` is allowing you to set the default value for new records.
The value is assigned when the record is inserted for the first time.
You can write FieldSelecting event handler and check the value of the field and set to the default one if the value is `null`.

Comment: +1 FieldSelecting is a magic bullet, whenever a field isn't returning the desired value on screen FieldSelecting will always reliably override the value.

Comment: Hi Samvel Petrosov,  my requirement is that the DB field initially should be 0.00.  I think Fieldselecting will make UI field as 0.00 but the DB field shows null.